# is this a valid xpath query?

Tags: javascript, json

`//[dataOptions[id]]` seems to work

But `//[dataOptions[id=value]]` doesn't work

I am trying to get all the parents of `dataOptions` where `dataOptions.id` equals `val`. Is the second one valid ? I have a doubt my JPath that I am using to resolve query has a bug. But I am not sure if my query is valid.

```
[
{
    "dataOptions": {
        "id": "id1",
        "count": "10"
    },
    "name": "Leon",
    "children": [
        {
            "dataOptions": {
                "id": "id2",
                "count": "10"
            },
            "name": "Leon",
            "children": [],
            "isExpanded": false
        },
        {
            "dataOptions": {
                "id": "id2",
                "count": "10"
            },
            "name": "Leon",
            "children": [],
            "isExpanded": false
        }
    ],
    "isExpanded": false
},
{
    "dataOptions": {
        "id": "id3",
        "count": "10"
    },
    "name": "Leon",
    "children": [],
    "isExpanded": false
},
{
    "dataOptions": {
        "id": "id4",
        "count": "10"
    },
    "name": "Leon",
    "children": [],
    "isExpanded": false
}
```

]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ShaggyInjun,
I think you're looking something in lines with:

```
//dataOptions[id]
//dataOptions[id="id2"]
```

I have recently written a js-lib called "defiant.js" - with which one can make queries on JSON structure with XPath. To put in in this context - I've pasted your JSON data at this page:

http://www.defiantjs.com/#xpath_evaluator

...and visually tested different XPath queries agains the structure. The evaluator highlights the matches both in JSON and its XML counterpart.

I hope you find the "defiant.js" and its site usefull.

Comment: Great job with DefiantJS. I will try and use this in my future endeavours. Thankyou for letting me know.

Answer (score 2):

> `//[dataOptions[id]]` seems to work
>
> But `//[dataOptions[id=value]]` doesn't work

***Both*** of these are with illegal syntax (the predicate must be preceded by a node - test).

> I am trying to get all the parents of `dataOption`s where
>   `dataOptions.id` equals `val`.

**Use**:

```
//*[dataOptions[id=val]]
```

this selects all elements that have a child element `dataOptions` whose `id` and `val` children have the same sting value.

**or use if `val` isn't an element name but a literal string, then use**:

```
//*[dataOptions[id='val']]
```

**UPDATE**: The OP has edited the question 3 hrs after initially asked -- *now* we see that the input is JSON. XPath doesn't know about JSON -- it only operates on XML documents. Therefore, this question shouldn't be tagged as XPath.

Comment: Thanks for the help. That didn't seem to do it. This the error I see. **ReferenceError: id is not defined** I think JPath has a bug. Here's the link if it peeks your interest.

http://bluelinecity.com/software/jpath/

Comment: Quick Question though. Provided there is no bug, should the above query return all the objects in all levels ? For example, should I see the object inside children returned?

Comment: @ShaggyInjun: Now that you edited the question and provided the "document" I see that this is JSON -- not XPath. XPath can *only be used on an XML document -- not on JSON. This question shouldn't be tagged "xpath".

Comment: @ShaggyInjun: Quick answer: Yes, if the input were an XML document. Now that you've edited the question and provided the input, we see it is JSON -- and XPath cannot be applied against a JSON object. You need to untag this from "xpath" and tag the question with a really relevant tag.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a place I can view the JSON data you're trying to use JPath against?

You can also try using the chained method of querying out your data.

```
var jp = new Path(JSONDATA);

jp.$('dataOptions').$(function(n){
    return( n.$('id').json == yourvalue );
}).json;
```

The XPath portion of JPath simply uses some regexp's to create code like above.

Comment: Thanks a million for JPath Bryan and for responding to my question. XPath is easier to use so I have been using that. Updated the question with json. Appreciate your help.

Comment: `jp.$('data').f("$('dataOptions').$('id').json =='" + key + "'").json;`

That above code returns the objects, but only the ones in the first level. All the further levels are ignored

Comment: If i understand what you're trying to grab from the data the below query should work for you. 

//*[dataOptions/id = 'someval']

or using the methods

jp.$$('*').$(function(n){ return(n.$('dataOptions/id').json == 'val'); }).json;

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I wish there was more documentation on JPath querying syntax.