# XPath predicate must be preceded by node test

Tags: xml, xpath

I have read all I could find but just wanted to confirm that the following is **NOT** a valid **XPath** expression because of the reason mentioned in the title.

```
//trip/[@trainID]
```

I already found that the expression

```
//trip[@trainID]
```

Selects all `trip` elements with the attribute called `trainID`,

and that the expression

```
//trip/@trainID
```

Selects all `trainID` attributes on `trip` elements.

I also had referred to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11174764/3066295).

> *Reason for the Question:*
>
> I knew that the part in brackets (i.e. ***predicate***) creates a filter.
>   I thought perhaps the expression in question would function like in the third expression above in the absence of any test on the attribute. But it did not work in my test and it was confirmed below the expression is simply not valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, `//trip/[@trainID]` is not a valid XPath.

Like you said in the title, a predicate must be proceeded by a node test.

From the [1.0 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#section-Location-Steps):

> ```
> [4]       Step       ::=      AxisSpecifier NodeTest Predicate*   
>                              | AbbreviatedStep
> ```

With NodeTest defined as:

> ```
> [7]       NodeTest       ::=      NameTest    
>                                  | NodeType '(' ')'   
>                                  | 'processing-instruction' '(' Literal ')'
> ```